# Rscript print a NULL in the windows

Tags: r, windows, rscript

```r
Rscript.exe -e "1"
# NULL
# [1] 1
```

`Rscript.exe` always prints a null in windows system.
Any method to forbid it?

#### Environment

- R: 4.3.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's likely coming from a profile file, either `Rprofile.site` or `.Rprofile`. See `?Startup` for information on where those files are found.

Use `Rscript --vanilla -e "1"` to avoid running them.